# Can I do hash merge by multiple keys in SAS

Tags: hash, merge, sas, key

I would like to hash merge in SAS using two keys;

The variable names for the lookup dataset called link_id 8. and ref_date 8.;
The variable names for the merged dataset called link_id 8. and drug_date 8.;

The code I used is as following:

```
data elig_bene_pres;
   length link_id ref_date 8.;
   call missing(link_id,ref_date):
   if _N_=1 then do;
      declare hash elig_bene(dataset:"bene.elig_bene_uid");
      elig_bene.defineKey("link_id","ref_date");
      elig_bene.defineDone();
   end;
   set data;
   if elig_bene.find(key:Link_ID,key:drug_dt)=0 then output;
run;
```

But it seems that it is not found by these two keys. I just want to know whether my method is doable.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have two values that match?

Comment: yes, actually the result shows all the rows of the data

Comment: Please provide some dummy data that we can use to reproduce your problem, along with the corresponding output you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious problems with the code.

To troubleshoot, try merge-sort: `PROC SORT` both data sets, then `merge` them `by` the two key variables. This will show which values look similar but are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This sample shows you have the correct approach.

```
data elig;
  input lukey1 lukey2; 
datalines;
1 1 
1 2
2 4
3 6
3 7
run;

data all;
  do key1 = 1 to 10; do key2 = 1 to 10;
    array x(5) (1:5);
    output;
  end; end;
run;

data all_elig;
  length lukey1 lukey2 8;
  call missing (lukey1,lukey2);
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash elig (dataset:"elig");
    elig.defineKey ('lukey1','lukey2');
    elig.defineDone ();
  end;
  set all;
  if 0 = elig.find(key:key1, key:key2);
run;
```

The process as shown is not really a merge because the lookup hash has no explicit data elements.  The keys are implicit data when no data is specified.

If you are selecting all data rows, the first item to troubleshoot is the `bene.elig_bene_uid`.  Are it's keys accidentally a superset of `data`'s ?